# How to pass data in fullcalendar in reactjs and retrive in handleDateClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fullcalendar

I have a post calendar for display post date wise, I used fullcalendar react module for that. How can I get post_id from the event object after clicking on the date

```
constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        events:[
            {
                "date": "2020-10-19",
                "data": {
                    post_id: 5
                }
            },
            {
                "date": "2020-10-20",
                "data": {
                    post_id: 6
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}


handleDateClick = (info) => {
    info.jsEvent.preventDefault();
    console.log(info)
}

render(){
    return(
        <FullCalendar
            plugins={[ dayGridPlugin, interactionPlugin ]}
            initialView="dayGridMonth"
            dateClick={this.handleDateClick}
            eventContent={this.renderEventContent}
            events={events}
            height={550}
        /> 
    )
}
```

how can I get post_id in handleDateClick function? when I clicked on the date I just get date.

Comment: dateClick handles clicks on the empty part of the day, away from the events themselves. If you want to handle the situation when someone clicks on an event, then use eventClick - https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventClick . The clue's in the name!!

Comment: Thanks, @ADyson It solved my issue and I got my data by using the extendedProps parameter.